# Python Run Error: No module named 'clickhouse_connect' while this module are already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-module

Can`t figure out why my python script are not run on pc (but in jupyter notebook all works)/

Error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clickhouse_connect'. I installed this module but still get this error.

```
import clickhouse_connect

client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(host='my_host',
                                       port=1111, username='name', password='my_password')
```

I tryed install several times. The cmd answer:

```
C:\Users\lvakhitova>pip install clickhouse_connect
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: clickhouse_connect in c:\users\lvakhitova\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (0.6.6)
Requirement already satisfied: lz4 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from clickhouse_connect) (3.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from clickhouse_connect) (4.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from clickhouse_connect) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.26 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from clickhouse_connect) (1.26.14)
Requirement already satisfied: zstandard in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from clickhouse_connect) (0.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from clickhouse_connect) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata->clickhouse_connect) (3.11.0)
```

The clickhouse_connect module already installed, in anaconda and python. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The usual cause of this problem is that you are running your code in an IDE that has its own installation of Python.  How, exactly, are you running this script?  Are you using in an IDE?

Comment: Hey! I`m running on IDLE Shell 3.11.4

Comment: If you look carefully at the `pip install` message, you can see that it says the `clickhouse_connect` module is in the 3.10 site packages. Is it possible you are installing the module into your 3.10 installation not your 3.11 one.

Comment: Yes, turn out that I have python 3.10 and python 3.11 all modules are in 3.10 version, but IDLE Shell 3.11.4 can`t see them  and I get error:


= RESTART: C:\Users\lvakhitova\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts\utm_auto_report.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lvakhitova\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts\utm_auto_report.py", line 7, in <module>
    import clickhouse_connect
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clickhouse_connect'

Is that mean that IDLE version and python 3.10 have conflict?

Comment: It doesn't mean they have a conflict, but it means they are different installations.  You need to install this module through the IDLE shell to make sure it's being installed into IDLE's installation of Python.